# Lexer written in Rust

Tags: beginner, parsing, rust, lexical-analysis

So I ported a lexer I wrote in C++ over to rust, as I'm starting to learn rust. Since I'm very new though, I don't know any Idioms and good practices in rust. So if anyone could point out some (probably obvious) issues I'd be very thankful.

This is my code:

```
use std::cmp::PartialEq;
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Token {
    EOF,
    Ident(String),
    Str(String),
    FNum(f64),
    INum(u64),
    Assign,
    BLsh,
    BRsh,
    BURsh,
    If,
    Else,
    Elif,
    Loop,
    Stop,
    Skip,
    Yes,
    No,
    Nope,
    Fun,
    Ret,
    And,
    Not,
    Or,
    LBrack,
    LBrace,
    LPar,
    RBrack,
    RBrace,
    RPar,
    Semi,
    Comma,
    Get,
    Concat,
    IDiv,
    FDiv,
    Add,
    Minus,
    Mul,
    Mod,
    BXOr,
    BAnd,
    BOr,
    IE,
    EQ,
    NE,
    LT,
    LE,
    GT,
    GE,
}

macro_rules! peek_char {
    ($e:expr) => {
        match $e.peek().cloned() {
            Some(c) => c,
            None => {
                return Token::EOF;
            }
        }
    };
}

pub fn get_token(iterator: &mut std::iter::Peekable<std::str::Chars>) -> Token {
    let mut next: char = peek_char!(iterator);
    let mut current_token: String = String::new();

    if next.is_whitespace() {
        loop {
            next = peek_char!(iterator);
            if !next.is_whitespace() {
                break;
            }
            iterator.next();
        }
        get_token(iterator)
    } else if next == '#' {
        loop {
            next = peek_char!(iterator);
            if next == '\n' {
                break;
            }
            iterator.next();
        }
        get_token(iterator)
    } else if next.is_alphabetic() {
        loop {
            next = match iterator.peek().cloned() {
                Some(c) => c,
                None => {
                    break;
                }
            };
            if !(next.is_alphanumeric() || next == '_') {
                break;
            }
            iterator.next();
            current_token.push(next);
        }
        match current_token.as_str() {
            "if" => Token::If,
            "else" => Token::Else,
            "elif" => Token::Elif,
            "loop" => Token::Loop,
            "stop" => Token::Stop,
            "skip" => Token::Skip,
            "yes" => Token::Yes,
            "no" => Token::No,
            "nope" => Token::Nope,
            "fun" => Token::Fun,
            "return" => Token::Ret,
            "and" => Token::And,
            "not" => Token::Not,
            "or" => Token::Or,
            _ => Token::Ident(current_token),
        }
    } else if next == '"' {
        iterator.next();
        loop {
            next = peek_char!(iterator);
            let to_add: char = if next == '\\' {
                iterator.next();
                next = peek_char!(iterator);
                match next {
                    't' => '\t',
                    'b' => '\x08',
                    'n' => '\n',
                    'r' => '\r',
                    'f' => '\x0c',
                    '"' => '"',
                    '\\' => '\\',
                    _ => panic!("unknown escaped character"),
                }
            } else if next == '"' {
                iterator.next();
                break;
            } else {
                next
            };
            iterator.next();
            current_token.push(to_add);
        }
        Token::Str(current_token)
    } else if next.is_digit(10) {
        loop {
            next = match iterator.peek().cloned() {
                Some(c) => c,
                None => {
                    break;
                }
            };
            if !(next.is_digit(10) || next == '.') {
                break;
            }
            iterator.next();
            if next == '.' && current_token.contains('.') {
                panic!("multiple decimal points in number");
            }
            current_token.push(next);
        }
        if current_token.contains('.') {
            Token::FNum(
                current_token
                    .parse::<f64>()
                    .expect("error reading float literal"),
            )
        } else {
            Token::INum(
                u64::from_str_radix(&current_token, 10).expect("error reading integer literal"),
            )
        }
    } else if next == '/' {
        iterator.next();
        next = match iterator.peek().cloned() {
            Some(c) => c,
            None => {
                return Token::FDiv;
            }
        };
        if next == '/' {
            iterator.next();
            Token::IDiv
        } else {
            Token::FDiv
        }
    } else if next == '?' {
        iterator.next();
        next = peek_char!(iterator);
        iterator.next();
        if next == '=' {
            Token::IE
        } else {
            panic!("unknown character");
        }
    } else if next == '!' {
        iterator.next();
        next = peek_char!(iterator);
        iterator.next();
        if next == '=' {
            Token::NE
        } else {
            panic!("unknown character");
        }
    } else if next == '=' {
        iterator.next();
        next = match iterator.peek().cloned() {
            Some(c) => c,
            None => {
                return Token::Assign;
            }
        };
        if next == '=' {
            iterator.next();
            Token::EQ
        } else {
            Token::Assign
        }
    } else if next == '<' {
        iterator.next();
        next = match iterator.peek().cloned() {
            Some(c) => c,
            None => {
                return Token::LT;
            }
        };
        if next == '=' {
            iterator.next();
            Token::LE
        } else if next == '<' {
            iterator.next();
            Token::BLsh
        } else {
            Token::LT
        }
    } else if next == '>' {
        iterator.next();
        next = match iterator.peek().cloned() {
            Some(c) => c,
            None => {
                return Token::GT;
            }
        };
        if next == '=' {
            iterator.next();
            Token::GE
        } else if next == '>' {
            iterator.next();
            next = match iterator.peek().cloned() {
                Some(c) => c,
                None => {
                    return Token::BRsh;
                }
            };
            if next == '>' {
                iterator.next();
                Token::BURsh
            } else {
                Token::BRsh
            }
        } else {
            Token::GT
        }
    } else {
        iterator.next();
        match next {
            '[' => Token::LBrack,
            '{' => Token::LBrace,
            '(' => Token::LPar,
            ']' => Token::RBrack,
            '}' => Token::RBrace,
            ')' => Token::RPar,
            ';' => Token::Semi,
            '.' => Token::Get,
            ',' => Token::Comma,
            '+' => Token::Add,
            '-' => Token::Minus,
            '*' => Token::Mul,
            '%' => Token::Mod,
            '$' => Token::Concat,
            '^' => Token::BXOr,
            '&' => Token::BAnd,
            '|' => Token::BOr,
            _ => panic!("unknown character"),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of general notes:

- I’m not sure why you used a macro for `peek_char!`. I’m relatively certain this could have been a standard function.
- Take some time to learn about slices.
- You have a single, several hundred line function there. It’s hard to read and follow. Extract lots of well named functions to improve readability.
- If you `panic` inside your function, there’s not really any way for the person calling your function to handle it. This should return a `Result<Token, ParseError>`.